# Get info about user signed in from native application

Tags: android, google-plus

I have an android application which has a working 'sign in'.

There are multiple options of Google Accounts to sign in from (no news here).

Is there a way to know if the user which signed in to *my* application is the same as the user
that signed into the actual Google+ application?

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want to know whether the user who is signed into your app that integrates Google+ Sign-In is the same user who is currently signed into the Google+ application? Or, do you have a web implementation with Google+ Sign-In and want to see if the user on an Android app is the same user as on your site...

Comment: thanks for the answer. the first option. is user logged into my app integrating g+ the same as the user who is logged into the physical g+ application.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, I'll come back if I can figure out anything...